# Inheritance and discriminator in base class

Tags: c#, swagger, nswag

I have class operation:

```
public class Operation
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public OperationOptions Options { get; set; }
}
```

Where value of `Type` defines type of `Options`. But I have to add `discriminator` to `OperationOptions` type

```
[KnownType(typeof(EchoOptions))]
[KnownType(typeof(VetDocumentAcceptanceOptions))]
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonInheritanceConverter), "discriminator")]
public class OperationOptions
{
}

public class EchoOptions : OperationOptions
{
}

public class VetDocumentAcceptanceOptions : OperationOptions
{
}
```

So I get in swagger.json:

```
  "OperationOptions": {
    "type": "object",
    "discriminator": {
      "propertyName": "discriminator",
      "mapping": {
        "EchoOptions": "#/components/schemas/EchoOptions",
        "VetDocumentAcceptanceOptions": "#/components/schemas/VetDocumentAcceptanceOptions"
      }
    }
```

But I don't have property `Discriminator` in `OperationOptions` in my model.

Is there any way to use `Type` in `Operation` as discriminator for `OperationOptions`?

Comment: Maybe related: https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/issues/668

Answer (score 0):

The `JsonInheritanceConverter` will automatically add the `discriminator` property to the serialized JSON and use this property when deserializing JSON to a type to select the correct type. It's better to actually not see the property as a C# property.